# c++17 `filesystem` is not a namespace-name

Tags: c++, g++, std, c++17

I am wondering why in the following code, the namespace `filesystem` is not found:

> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -lstdc++

```
// #include <filesystem>   <- error, so changed to the following:
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
main.cpp:3:21: error: ‘filesystem’ is not a namespace-name
 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
                     ^
main.cpp:3:31: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
 namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

> gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)

Comment: If your compiler is older than the standard you are trying to use, there is only so much compliance you can expect.

Comment: `std::filesystem` support in g++ starts at version 8.0

Comment: Also, to be able to link, you have to add the `-lstdc++fs` option to g++. See notes in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Comment: Works fine for me in `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Comment: Even compiler is new, if project is not configured with 17 support then, you will see this error: in CMAKE set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17), will fix the problem. In Autoconf you also need to update C++ version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GCC 5.4.0 was released in June of 2016; over a year before the C++17 standard was adopted.  It and its version of libstdc++ have very limited C++17 support.  You can see when GCC added C++17 language features [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) and when libstdc++ added C++17 standard library features [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017).

At the time of GCC 5.4's release, the filesystem library was not yet implemented in the `std::filesystem` namespace.  It, along with any other <experimental/...> headers that are included in that version, are in the `std::experimental` namespace.

Comment: Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: @SamZiggler Any solution for what?  If you must use an old compiler, then you'll have to include the appropriate experimental header and use `std::experimental::filesystem`.  You could use some preprocessor checks to set things up if you want to be compatible with a wide range of compiler versions.

Answer (score 22):

`<experimental/..>` means experimental namespace:

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio go and change the C++ language standard

- Right-click the project name
- Go to the general tab and select the Iso c++ 20
  [image]