# How to read files from a directory in c++ in a platform independent way?

Tags: c++, filesystems, cross-platform

I have an assignment that require me to develop a program that is passed
either a file name or a directory name.

if what is passed is a directory name then i have to read all the files in that directory and basically do some processing on them.

the problem is that I am using c++ and c++ out of the box doesn't really play nice with file systems without third party/system libs.

how can I read all the files from a directory without platform dependency because I am using a windows machine and the grader is using linux machine.

I tried to use filesystem and I have gcc 9.2 but it doesn't compile

it doesn't compile this file:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){
    
    fs::path p("some-path");
 
}
```

it results in this compiler error:

```
testfs.cpp:4:21: error: 'filesystem' is not a namespace-name
    4 | namespace fs = std::filesystem;
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~
testfs.cpp: In function 'int main()':
testfs.cpp:8:5: error: 'fs' has not been declared
    8 |     fs::path p("some-path");
```

Comment: GCC 9.2 doesn't default to compiling to the c++17 standard revision, the first to support filesystem. Force it  by adding `-std=c++17` to the command line. Examples with and without : https://godbolt.org/z/Tj6car

Comment: I'm utterly flabbergasted that I can't find a decent duplicate for this.

Comment: "c++ out of the box doesn't really play nice with file systems" Your compiler error aside (which isnt "c++ playing with the filesystem") it is not clear what general problem you refer to

Comment: @user4581301 same question but different gcc version and flags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312460/c17-filesystem-is-not-a-namespace-name

Comment: Saw that one. The killer there was more the GCC version predates the C++17 release/

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980383/how-to-determine-what-c-standard-is-the-default-for-a-c-compiler/46980534

Comment: Don't forget to input library name `stdc++fs` if you're using `gcc`.

Comment: it worked after I added -std=c++17, g++ didn't compile to c++17 by default indeed

Answer (score 1):

`filesystem::path` is by far the best cross-platform solution for platforms with a compiler that supports C++17, the first to support `filesystem`, or a newer Standard revision.

GCC 9.2 doesn't default to compiling to the c++17 standard revision.

Force C++ 17 support by adding `-std=c++17` to the command line, selecting the C++17 dialect in your IDE's Compiler option property pages, or editing the appropriate configuration file to add the option.

Examples with and without the extra compiler option: https://godbolt.org/z/Tj6car

If a C++17 or newer compiler is not available on your system, consider using [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: it worked after I added -std=c++17, g++ didn't compile to c++17 by default indeed