# How to apply C++17 standard in this g++?

Tags: g++

My g++ version is Ubuntu 5.4.0:

```
    g++ --version
    g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
```

From the man page, I see this:

```
       c++14
       c++1y
           The 2014 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.  The name c++1y is deprecated.

       gnu++14
       gnu++1y
           GNU dialect of -std=c++14.  The name gnu++1y is deprecated.

       c++1z
           The next revision of the ISO C++ standard, tentatively planned for 2017.  Support
           is highly experimental, and will almost certainly change in incompatible ways in
           future releases.
```

Does that mean "-std=c++1z" for c++17? I am confused what should be used for c++17 because some programs just use "-std=c++17" directly and compiled successfully using this g++.

Comment: Isn't this something you can answer yourself just by trying it? The compiler should  tell you if it's a valid option or not, so you can try `-std=c++17` and see if you get an error message.

Comment: right, my question sounded a weird one. I did try -std=c++17 for some code but it failed when using "inline static" feature in c++17. But some other installations using -std=c++17 with this g++ worked just fine. So that's why I am confused

Comment: I don't think your version of G++ is current enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48312534/62576 and https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: Thanks. The first link says this g++ has limited c++17 support so that may explain why some code worked while other didn't. Do you happen to know how to upgrade g++ in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Umm...  At gcc.gnu.org?

Comment: I was thinking do a "sudo apt-upgrade...". But seemed many variants doing this and don't want to mess up current system

Comment: You should ask how to do this upgrade on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: I used these 3 steps upgrade from 5.4.0 to gcc/g++8: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8. These 3 steps worked and c++17 is already the default version. No need to specify -std=c++17 anymore

Answer (score 0):

These 3 steps can update Ubuntu gcc/g++ from default 5.4.0 to 8:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install gcc-8 g++-8