# filesystem namespace problems with C++17

Tags: c++, filesystems

Having troubles accessing the filesystem namespace -

**Problem:**

- "*Symbol 'filesystem' could not be resolved*"`

**Leading Research:**

1. [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) - Stack Overflow
2. [C++17 Filesystem](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5659/c17-filesystem) - Codingame

**Setup:**

1. GCC/G++: 9.2.0
2. C++: C++17

**Demo:**

[File Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly0jh36bmydbu55/fileDemo_0.zip?dl=0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
    
int main(void) {    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the [std::experimental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312460/) variant to no success. How can I get C++17 & the `<filesystem>` API working?

**Soln Update:**

Thank you [P Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16649550/p-kramer), w/MSYS2 I was able to quickly come to solution.

*Procedure:*

1. Get [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) (*msys2-x86_64-20210725.exe*)
2. Run the installer (@loc  C:\Sw\msys64)
3. pacman -Syu
4. pacman -Su
5. pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
6. Check w/cmd (C:\Sw\msys64\mingw64\bin)
7. gcc -v (GCC v10.3.0)
8. Add to path (C:\Sw\msys64\mingw64\bin, C:\Sw\msys64\usr\bin)
9. Restart Eclipse
10. Demo compile to confirm C++17 (__cplusplus == 201703L)
11. Use it!

[Final Working Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m61nem2s8edzzot/fileDemo_1.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++17` specified?

Answer (score 1):

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html mentions incomplete filesystem implementation on windows. Goto compiler explorer and compile your sample with gcc 9.2 first. See here : https://godbolt.org/z/q9vTcernn
This will indeed fail, if you change to latest gcc (for windows) everything compiles fine.

So the problem is the compiler version you are using.

Comment: Hallelujah it works!! Will post my answer in a bit, this was sincerely appreciated thanks